# Create Empty SoapUI project Using Java

Tags: java, api, soapui

I need to create an empty SoapUI project. Using the GUI I can do this easily, but I want to do it using the Java API. Currently I am trying like this, but it doesn't work.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject (project_path);
}
}
```

Comment: There is a [post](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Build-SoapUI-Project-files-with-Java/m-p/38265/highlight/true#M15380) on the SmartBear forum describing how to do it.

Comment: Hi, I have read the post. It works if I have a wsdl file. But I want to create an empty project.

Comment: I would create a empty project and use it's XML as a template, ignoring the SoapUI API for that task.